# Use RESTful WCF Service with HTTP request

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, rest

I try to consume a [RESTful WCF Service](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-RESTful-WCF-e5e8d405) by making POST requests with the [DHC Plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm). Unfortunately I have no idea how the JSON request should look like.

The relevant parts of the VB.NET project

**IUserService.vb**

```
<OperationContract(),
    WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
              UriTemplate:="/User/Create",
              RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
              BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Sub CreateUser(ByVal user As User)
```

**UserService.svc.vb**

```
Public Sub CreateUser(ByVal user As User) Implements IUserService.CreateUser
    user.UserObject.CreateUser(user)
End Sub
```

**User.vb**

```
Private m_Id As Integer
Private m_Name As String
Private m_Age As Integer
Private m_Sex As Sex
Private m_Comments As String
Private Shared m_UserObj As User
Private m_LUser As List(Of User)

Public Shared ReadOnly Property UserObject() As User
    Get
        If m_UserObj Is Nothing Then
            m_UserObj = New User()
        End If

        Return m_UserObj
    End Get
End Property

Friend Sub CreateUser(ByVal user As User)
    LUser.Add(user)
End Sub

Public Enum Sex
    Male = 0
    Female = 1
End Enum
```

I have tried something like this without success (Response: **400 Bad request**):
[image: JSON POST request]

How should the POST request look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added this headers:

1. Content-Type: application/json
2. Accept: application/json

and it works like a charm